# highlight background color if the answer is accepted

Tags: feature-request, design

under our profiles Activity page, if we want to check the answer is accepted or not, its bit difficult to find out for someone who have bad eyes like me :)

[image]

what all i wanted is if at all possible, please highlight background color if answer is accepted as like Stack OOOOverflow....

[image]

Comment: Isn't that already the case ? The background of the number of answer cell is highlighted in green ? Lighter green than SO but still visible to me

Comment: @RaphaelatDigitalPianism you are absolutely right,  it's visible for me too, but i thought if they `highlight` than it ll be better, as you said still its fine.....

Comment: @7ochem thanks for editing & made  this post complete , you are `Mr.peRFect` of our community.....

Comment: Actually it's not only about perfection or esthetics, if you add the design tag, I think the SE design team is watching that tag and you will have more chance on a fast response from the SE design team.

Comment: @7ochem That's fantastic information  & i told peRFect not for adding `design` tag & its for your overall contribution or the community :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Compare to eldest sister "stackoverflow" , the Backgroud-color is less, but still we can identify which answer is accepted or not, if stack team highlight the background color, than it ll be fantastic.... if they don't do also still its fine....

[image]